Prevent clickable div from being searched in Android WebView
Theres a google search drawer that appears if you repeatedly touch on a div, I guess it is to help you search for whatever is in the div's content.
How can i prevent it from opening? (Especially when im using divs as a gamepad)
It appears like in the picture below.

